# Display 500k rows in WebBrowser using WebSockets

Tags: javascript, ajax, websocket

I'm using similar grid like - [datatable](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/server-side_processing.html) to display 500k rows for client. If you scroll the grid you will see small delay in 50 msec. In real application depends on round-trip it may be up to 200 msec.

I'm trying to implement fast search + endless scrolling like without visible delay. When access not previously accessed part of the grid, data is loaded via Ajax and cached locally. Sometimes I need to rebuild whole grid and invalidate local cache, if user change sorting/searching. Searching is very complicated and can't be done on client side.

I can't cache whole grid on client using single Ajax call because the return size even with enabled compression is about 1-2MB. Now the data is loaded via chunks by multiple Ajax calls.

I have never worked with WebSockets before. Can I have some benefits by using WebSockets ? I suspect that streaming chunks via WebSockets should be faster then multiple Ajax calls

Let's say I creation of Ajax request, sending request and parsing response takes 40 msec. Will it be faster to request and receive new chunk using WebSockets ?

Comment: You'd still need to chunk-you can always scroll faster than a round-trip, even with sockets.

Comment: @DaveNewton For now I understand current scroll position, cancel current ajax request and create new one with current position. With websockets I can simply request another chunk

Comment: Well this is highly dependent on the situation but, if you have a 20 mbit connection (which is pretty low for today's standards) you would download all the data in 1 second?